# Given an array of long strings, how do I efficiently check given pairs of substrings (of the given strings) if they differ by at most one character?

Tags: c, string, substring, string-matching

Any given pair of substrings are of the same length. Many pairs of substrings have to be checked, so a naive compare is not efficient enough, but I can't really think of any preprocessing of the array of strings that would help speed up the compare process. Thanks in advance!

An example is provided for clarification:

an array of long strings:

```
str = {"aaaaa", "aaabbcc", "abcdefgh"...}
```

pairs of substrings to be checked:

```
pairs = {(str[0][0..1],str[1][1..2]), (str[0][1..4],str[2][3..6]), (str[1][2..4], str[2][0..2])...}
```

pairs of substrings to be checked (substituted in):

```
pairs = {("aa","aa"), ("aaaa","defg"), ("abb","abc")...}
```

the final result:

```
result = {true, false, true}
```

A naive compare would result in a runtime of `O(|pairs|*max(|str[i]|))`, and I would like to improve that.

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far?

Comment: There is [a variety of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm) that perform substring searching faster than naively comparing each pair of substrings.  I suggest reviewing some to try to identify one that you can modify to serve your purpose.  It's still going to be costly, but N^3 is better than N^4.

Comment: @MrPromethee I haven't done much other than doing naive string matching. I also did a checksum so that I only match strings with checksum differences of less than 128 (ascii). Still, this does not improve on the worst case, which is when all pairs of substrings happen to be the same/differ by one character.

Comment: Are you looking for matching substrings inside each of the long strings? Or across all long strings? Or between two of them? Is the length of the substrings given, i.e. an input value?

Comment: @MOehm A pair of substrings is given with their respective indicies, for instance str[4] [7..25] (the 4th string from the 7th to 25th character) and str[9][0..18] (the 9th string from the 0th to 18th character), and many pairs are provided to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Cross-posting my answer from Quora here).

IMO, the question was not stated very clearly, but I think it seems to be asking the following: we are given a set of strings S[1], S[2], …, S[N], and a set of queries which each take the form (i1, j1, i2, j2, L). The answer to such a query is “yes” if the strings of length L starting at position j1 of S[i1] and at position j2 of S[i2] differ by a change in at most one character, otherwise “no”. The sum of the L-values across all such queries may be much larger than the total length of the strings.

In that case, we can devise an efficient algorithm using the following observation: if S and T are strings of length L, then the statement “S and T differ by a change in at most one character” is equivalent to “LCP(S, T) + LCP(R(S), R(T)) >= L-1” where R denotes reversal of a string, and LCP is the length of the longest common prefix of two strings.

Thus, in order to answer queries efficiently, we only need to preprocess the strings S[1], …, S[N] and R(S[1]), …, R(S[N]) so that longest-common-prefix queries are fast. This can be done by concatenating S[1], …, S[N] to give one string S, and building the [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) and [longest-common-prefix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array) of S, then doing the same for the reverse of S. Determining the LCP of two substrings of the original strings is then equivalent to determining the LCP of two substrings of S (*) which is equivalent to a range-minimum-query in the LCP array, which can be answered efficiently by preprocessing. A similar statement holds for the reverses of the original strings and the reverse of S.

(*) Technically, the LCP in the concatenated string S can extend beyond the boundaries of the original strings. However, this would only happen if the query substrings were in fact identical, so it would just mean we would answer “yes” in cases where the answer is “yes” anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using suffix trees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

First convert all strings into suffix trees. This can be done in O(n) time where n is the length of the string.

Then you can recursively try all possible strings to see if they are a substring of at least 2 strings.

You start of with a set including pointers to the root of all trees. This reflects that '' is a substring of all strings. Then for every char find the subset of trees that has a matching child. E.g. for 'a' find all the pointers that in the set that have a child labeled 'a'. For any non empty set you have found a new common substring and you recurse to check for a longer one.

If you want to allow for one difference then the recursive call must also include the number of differences so far. If it is 1 then only matching children are allowed. If it is 0 then you can also recurse for each pair (c1, c2) where one string has a child c1 and some others have a child c2.

I think the overall runtime of this to be O(n * m + m * k * m * l) where n is the maximum length of a string and m their number, k the number of substrings you find and l the maximum length of substring you find.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm afraid that is not what I want. My problem is I have a bunch of pairs of given substrings (of the array of long strings) of equal length that I would like to compare if the pair of substrings differ by one or fewer characters. The naive method would have a runtime of O(n*m) where n is the number of pairs and m is the maximum length of the substrings. I'm hoping that some kind of preprocessing can reduce the time complexity to lower than O(n*log(m)).

Comment: That makes no sense. Why should anything make it logarithmic with the length of the substring? Only way to get around the naive runtime I see is when a given substring appears in many pairs. And then the above would apply.